# Design android material card view in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

How can I design material design card view in cn1? It can be done pretty easily in android native and react native etc. But I'm confused how easily can it be done in cn1 with all those shadows and card radius etc. Is there any example on it? Plz see the design below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can use `RoundRectBorder` in the designer tool or through CSS. It includes support for the slight roundness of the corners as well as support for shadows. Just place containers with that styling in a BoxLayout Y.

Comment: Hello @shai, I can set how big is the shadow through shadowSpread. By doing this, the shadow will expand uniformly all around the component. I want to expand the shadow differently in horizontal and vertical axis. How can I do that? Is there a way so that I can set shadowSpreadHorizontally(5) and shadowSpreadvertically(20)?

Comment: You need to define the shadowX/Y to a value between 0 and 1 which will determine the projection position of the shadow relatively to the component where 0.5 indicates a light source just on top of the component.

Comment: I had set shadowY(0.3f) and shadowSpread(25) which makes the top shadow smaller than the bottom (it is smaller than left and right shadows as well). Left and right shadows are of equal width. But I want the width of left and right shadow equal to the top shadow which is smaller than all the other shadows in the component. If shadowX() is used the one side of the shadow is bigger and other smaller.